# Multiple vars in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want create a user's page, like twitter, who have more options, like: `site.com/u/User` but i want create multiples, like: `site.com/u/User`, `site.com/u/User/photos`, i try it:

`RewriteRule ^u/(.+)$ perfil/?user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)/t$ perfil/?user=$1&t=1 [L,QSA]`

But it doesn't works, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot, i founded it, lol, i found here http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Just change `(.*)` to `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`